# Comparing entries in a list to another list

Tags: python, list, generator

Using Python 3.9.5

```
a=['Apple', 'Orange', 'peaches']

b=[['Lettuce', 'Apple', 'eggs'],['potato', 'tomato', 'pepper']]
```

I want to compare for any values in a to b  and if there is a match continue to the next list (
my program generates lists of key words) i want to compare the initial list "a" to the lists i have and if there is a match go next and if there is no match then do something like print that list.

this is what i tried, not working though

```
for i in b:
   if any(x in a for x in [b, c]):
      continue 
   else:
       print(#the current sublist)
```

i would like to say that with integers this code works but with lists or strings it doesn't, appreciate the feedback

Comment: Sorry I mean lists of integers it works but lists of strings it doesn't.

Comment: You should edit the question rather than posting edits in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'peaches']
b = [['Lettuce', 'Apple', 'eggs'], ['potato', 'tomato', 'pepper']]

for el in b:
    if any([x in a for x in el]):
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(el)
```

Returns:

```
True
False
```

**Explanation**:

1. First of all we iterate over `b`, so we have `el = ['Lettuce', 'Apple', 'eggs']` on the first iteration.
2. Next we create list of bools: `[x in a for x in el]`. We check are there elements of `a` in our current element `el`: `[False, True, False]` - for first element of `b`.
3. Next we reduce our list of bools (`[False, True, False]`) to one bool using `any()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where are you are getting the variable `c`. Just replace this line and it will work.

From:

```
if any(x in a for x in [b,c]):
```

To:

```
if any(x in a for x in i):
```

The value of `i` is each sub-list in `b` such as `['Lettuce', 'Apple', 'eggs']` thus your algorithm iterates each item in the sub-list and checks for any element that is also in `a`.

---

Here is an improvement to your algorithm. Currently, your algorithm runs at a time complexity of `O(z * y * x)` where:

- x = length of `a`
- y = length of `b`
- z = average length of each sub-list in `b`

Instead of always traversing the list `a`, make it a hash table e.g. set, this will make the searches improve from linear `O(x)` to constant `O(1)`.

```
a_set = set(a)

for i in b:
   if any(x in a_set for x in i):
       # Do something or just continue
      continue 
   else:
       print(i)
```

This will improve the time complexity to `O(z * y)`. As a comparison, if we have 20 elements in `a`, 10 in `b`, and an average of 3 in each sub-list of `b`, the previous algorithm using a list `a` would run 3 * 10 * 20 for a total of 600 iterations, compare to a set `a` which would only run 3 * 10 for a total of 30 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

That should work if I understand the problem correctly:

```
to_check = ['Apple','Orange','peaches']

list_of_lists = [['Lettuce', 'Apple','eggs'],['potato','tomato','pepper']]

for _list in list_of_lists:
    if any([element_to_check in _list for element_to_check in to_check]):
        print('Matched')
    else:
        print('Not matched')
```